# How to collect only the latest entries from a table by user

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a transaction table. I need to make a query that needs to pull the latest entries by client_id.

> ```
> 8 UK0619344 Mr Stephen  Cutt        XS1923339623    50000   25/10/2019 16:57
> 9   UK0619344   Mr Stephen Cutt         XS1923339623    40000   27/10/2019 16:58
> 11  UK081831    Mrs Elizabeth Nicholls  XS1877205325    10000   25/10/2019 16:58
> 12  UK081833    Mr Andrew James         XS1890026708    15000   19/10/2019 13:11
> 13  UK081833    Mr Andrew James         XS1890026708    10000   21/10/2019 16:00
> 14  UK081831    Mrs Elizabeth Nicholls  XS1877205325    6000    11/10/2019 11:00
> ```

For example, Mr. Stephen Cutt has multiple entries but I need to pick the latest one.

Same for Mr. Andrew James pick the entry of 21/10/2019

I tried the following queries, but not getting the data I want.

```php
$details =DB::table('transactions')
              ->groupBy('created_at')
              ->latest()
              ->get();
```

and

```php
$details =DB::table('transactions')
              ->groupBy('client_id')
              ->latest()
              ->get();
```

Need help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have another table for client ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
//For Mr. Stephen Cutt
$details = DB::table('transactions')->where('client_id','UK0619344')->latest()->get()

//For Both Mr. Stephen Cutt and Mr. Andrew James
$details = DB::table('transactions')->whereIn('client_id',['UK0619344','UK081833'])->latest()->get()

// Or If You Like to get Nested result, Group By Client
$details = Client::whereIn('client_id',['UK0619344','UK081833'])->with('transactions'=>function($query){
    return $query->whereDate('2019-10-21')->latest();
})->get()
```

Maybe Those could help you...

Comment: Hi Arif, thanks for your reply. But the id's are not fixed and i don't know which client to get. because this was a short example in the real table I have more than 100 clients data and after every transaction data gets saved here. So cant do a fixed query with fixed ID's.

Comment: ids are just example there. just tell me what you exactly want. latest transaction based client data or client based latest transaction data ?